# python pyCharm 'processing' package error not found

Tags: python, import, pycharm, processing, barcode

I was trying to generate a barcode by using this sample http://www.101computing.net/barcode-generator-using-python/

When I execute the code in PyCharm the below error is occurring on the very first line.

`from processing import *`

Error:
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/G/My Work/Learn/Python/Practice/BarCodeGen.py", line 1, in <module>
    from processing import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'processing'`

Can you provide an insight on how to import the package 'processing'.? Otherwise do you have any pointers on how to generate barcodes?

Comment: There are two possibilities to fix your problem: 1) you're using the wrong python environment in PyCharm which doesn't have `processing` installed; 2) you haven't installed `processing` via pip in the environment that you're using.

Answer (score 0):

There is a `processing` package [on pypi](https://pypi.org/project/processing/) but that doesn't seem to be the same `processing` package used in that specific online interpreter ([their docs](https://www.trinket.io/docs/python)). I suspect that the code in this tutorial is meant to only be ran inside of that specific online interpreter.

As for generating barcodes, I found two packages that could be useful. [python-barcode](https://pypi.org/project/python-barcode/) and [pyBarcode](https://pypi.org/project/pyBarcode/).

Comment: Yes, after installing the Python Barcode component, was able to generate the bar code. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, after installing the Python Barcode component, was able to generate the bar code. Thank you.